# Calling a method instead of an activity using an Intent - android developers

Tags: android

How can I fire a method instead of an Activity in my code?

I want to use the `AddProximityAlert()` method from the `LocationManager` but it needs an Intent to work and I don't want to call another activity since the method I want to fire is in the same `Activity` from where I'm using `AddProximityAlert()`

Goes like this:

```
public clase onCreate()
{
......

LocationManager LM; // already initialized

LM.addProximityAlert(lat,long,radio,expiration,INTENT) <--- This INTENT needs to call myMethod()

}

public void MyMethod()
{

.......

}
```

I have several hours trying to find a solution for this, and all I find is for calling another activity, please be as much specific, even if I have to do something with the `manifest.xml` because I haven't used intents before.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you create a android service (or broadcast receiver might be more appropriate) within the same application that handles the intent.

You don't leave the same pid, it's a non-visual service and you never leave your activity?

You can call your service directly by creating a intent the references it's class name directly.

```
       intent = new Intent(context, my_service.class);
```

It then will hit the services "onStartCommand()" function and you can do your intent processing from there.

Comment: thank you, I have been reading deeper about services and broadcast receiver and I think I will implement a bounded service to my main activity, thanks for enlighten me

Comment: It's kind of sad that the method addProximityAlert() does not interact within the main  application itself, it needs to invoke another one via an Intener, but whaterever.

Comment: Everything is there to write your own proximity alert. I assume it's because it uses another application, probably maps in order to complete it's functionality.